ipynb to pdf | Converting to jupyter notebook to pdf
I'm facing issue in downloading the ipynb nootebook to --pdf i've used the ctrl + p option but its saving only one sheet to pdf. Also tried other options like converting to html and then to pdf but it's not working for me. Anyone can help me regarding this issue by guiding step by step working process of it.
Can't download it by any of method. Guide me step by step of all dependencies etc requirements

You can use notebook-as-pdf library.
pip install notebook-as-pdf

https://pypi.org/project/notebook-as-pdf/

Here you can find 4 ways to export Jupyter Notebook as PDF
https://mljar.com/blog/jupyter-notebook-pdf/
